# ASP.NET Mvc: How to trigger a notification event after a date?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a planner web app using ASP.NET MVC 3.

One of the problem I don't know is how to automatically trigger an event(send mail whatever) when the time is one that spot?

Who can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would not make the web app handle that. Instead, I'd have a service that runs in the background or use the Windows Schedule to run certain application every x min/hour.

But with ASP.NET, you could start a background thread that calls some function every x time.

Here's more on that: http://flimflan.com/blog/SafelyRunningBackgroundThreadsInASPNET20.aspx

I hope this helps you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your front end asp.net site that allows configuration of events, you will need a backend service attached to the database that sends out the notifications. This back end service should keep track of the last time it processed events. It will wake up periodically and process all newer events. The period will be determined by how 'real time' you want your responses. Once every minute is probably as fine grain as you may need.

Answer (score 0):

Timed events can be handled with threads or a service.

The downside to threads and timers that's not often considered is that often IIS will restart, which will restart your threads and timers. A service is much more stable and will fire automatically every so often without requiring you to keep track of state data (such as the current time).

Answer (score 0):

A service or a scheduled task is the best fit for this problem, but if your hosting provider (assuming you aren't self-hosting) does not allow for this, or they want a lot more money for this ability, then an alternative you can consider,if running in .NET 4.0, it always having the application pool stay alive.

This blog post by Scott Guthrie describes how this can be done:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx