# Proper way to have a user notification

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering what is the best way to have a website created in ASP.Net MVC 4 C# to send off email and do other things when it needs to. I'll give you an example:

User A is to be notified via email 15 minutes before his appointment at 2:30pm central time. The system would then automatically send him an email at 2:15pm central time to remind him.

I know this is a simple question but I honestly don't want (unless that's the only way) to use a system where a it sits there and pings a page to check and send off notifications every minute (that's the only way I can think of as of right now.)

Comment: A separate Windows service is typically used for these tasks.  The website may or may not be running at the due time.  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936684/c-sharp-code-that-run-constantly-service-or-separate-thread/11936723#11936723) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816452/asp-net-mvc-how-to-trigger-a-notification-event-after-a-date/4823640#4823640).

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at [Quartz .Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).  It's a .Net port of Quartz for Java.  I've used it in the past for scheduling.  You should be able to just have it running on a Windows service in the background and create a timed event when a user needs a reminder that would fire off X minutes before Y time.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is through a window service.  Instead of pinging a page, you get the window service to constantly poll the database or your datasource to know the current schedule for the tasks.